# SVN with Eclipse (subclipse) command line works, subclipse doesn't (Network connection closed unexpectedly)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svn-ssh

My boss just set up SVN repository for a new project on a new server (ubuntu). In Eclipse I wasn't able to add the repository to SVN repositories, I kept getting "
    Network connection closed unexpectedly
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.".

In order to check out the svn repo I did:

```
svn co svn+ssh://d_dinchev@SOME.IP.ADDRESS/var/svn/repos/ PROJECT_NAME
```

Then I created a new project in Eclipse, using "source" the directory where I checked out the repository, Eclipse recognized the SVN repository but when I try to do SVN update/commit I keep getting 
"Network connection closed unexpectedly
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file."

If I do svn up/svn commit in the command line it works fine. Subclipse uses JavaHL 1.6.12 as svn interface.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.3 (if that even matters).

I have many other repositories that work fine with both command line and subclipse but their repositories are all in format:

http://repository.example.com/svn/

And in the current case my repository is in:

svn+ssh://d_dinchev@SOME.IP.ADDRESS/var/svn/repos

So I think it might have to do something with the protocol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case someone has this, the problem indeed was with "svn+ssh" protocol while using JavaHL Subversion interface. I switched to SVNKit from Eclipse -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN and now it works fine.

Comment: Indeed, installed and switched to the beta 1.7 of SVNKit and it fixed the issues I had as well

Comment: You Sir just made my day!

Answer (score 2):

I have many repositories functional through subclipse as well but I've never done one with svn+ssh. However, after reading a bit on [this](http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/subclipse-setup.html) site I am wondering if you might want to try using ssh keys. If you are unaware how to set up your keys [this](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html) web site should guide you through the process.

Edit: I see there was another answer in the meantime. Veseliq looks like he knows what he is talking about, however I'll leave this here as well as it can't hurt to use ssh keys...and it still could potentially fix your problem too if it is related to subclipse not knowing how to handle authentication via ssh or something.